# C# Chart use CustomLabels with scrollbar

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I don't understand something. If i don't use the customlabels, the chart will use the default label. And then if I move the scrollbar , the chart size won't adjust. The Chart view maintain the original size.

But if I use this code to change the label at **row 0.** (other rows don't have this problem)

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add((i) , 
    (i+1), (ntemp * 10).ToString(), 0, LabelMarkStyle.SideMark);
```

And Move the scrollbar, the chart View will be a little different for size. The chart will flicker, and I don't want it.

Thanks in advance.

Here is example

```
            Random rand = new Random();
            chart1.Series.Clear();

            var series = chart1.Series.Add("My Series");
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
            series.Color = Color.Black;

            series.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;

            for (int i = 10; i > 2; i--)
                series.Points.AddXY(i, (rand.Next(3600, 7200)), (rand.Next(30000, 80000)));
            var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];

            chartArea.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid; //最外圍的框框
            chartArea.BorderWidth = 10;

            chartArea.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;

            chartArea.AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;

            chartArea.AxisY2.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

            chartArea.AxisY2.Interval = 3600;
            chartArea.AxisY2.Minimum = 0;
            chartArea.AxisY2.Maximum = 86400;
            chartArea.AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 3600 * 4);

            for (int i = 0; i <= 24 * 6; i++)
            {

                int ntemp = i % 6;
                if (ntemp != 0)
                {
                    /*Problem Here !!*/
                    //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add((i) * 600, (i + 1) * 600, (ntemp * 10).ToString(), 0, LabelMarkStyle.Box);
                }
            }

            chartArea.CursorY.AutoScroll = true;
            chartArea.AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            chartArea.AxisY2.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
            chartArea.AxisY2.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;

        }
```

Comment: What .Net framework you're using? Winforms/WPF/Web?

Comment: c# .net Framework 4.0  winforms

Comment: what is chart1 ? where/how is it defined? which charting library are you using?

Comment: Sorry . this is chart1.And i use the toolbox to drag the chart control to my Form.

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1;

Comment: Yeah, figured that out ... now when you uncomment the **problem here** bit, and drag the scrollbar, it's all ugly and choppy. Is that the problem you're talking about, or is there something else?

Comment: Seems to me it happens because of the changes to the AxisY2 labels size, which causes the entire chart to be drawn again and not always in the same place because the top (Y2 labels) size changes.

Comment: Yes, it's my problem. And i try to set Y2 labels like this  `chartArea.AxisY2.LabelStyle.Font =  new Font("Arial Black", 10, FontStyle.Bold);` It can't solve this question.

I hope whatever i Operating. the Chart View always have same size.

Comment: No love to my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was intrigued about how and if this can be achieved with OxyPlot, and I think it can ...
Here's the code I've used, and here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

```
var model = new PlotModel("IntervalBarSeries") { LegendPlacement =  LegendPlacement.Outside };

var temp_serie = new IntervalBarSeries 
{ 
    Title = "IntervalBarSeries 1", 
    FillColor = OxyColors.Black
};

var categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Left,
    IsZoomEnabled = false,  // No zoom on this axis
    IsPanEnabled = false,   // Right mouse move won't affect this axis
    MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid
    ,StartPosition = 1, EndPosition = 0 // This will reverse the order

};

var valueAxis = new LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Top)
{
    MinimumPadding = 0.1, MaximumPadding = 0.1, 
    IsZoomEnabled = true, 
    MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
    MajorStep = 3600,
    AbsoluteMinimum = 0
};

for (int i = 10; i > 2; i--)
{
temp_serie.Items.Add(new IntervalBarItem { 
    Start = rand.Next(3600, 7200), 
    End = rand.Next(30000, 80000) 
});

categoryAxis.Labels.Add("Activity "+i);
}

model.Series.Add(temp_serie);   
model.Axes.Add(categoryAxis);
model.Axes.Add(valueAxis);

MyPlotModel = model;
```

Now, I'm using MVVM and just binding to the plot model from my View with:

```
<oxy:Plot Model="{Binding MyPlotModel}"/>
```

But you can figure out how to do the same with WinForms once (if?) you decide to use OxyPlot and import it.

I'm assuming you're doing some work that is related to times, but your code obviously doesn't say so ... you could play around with the top header, and maybe set how to show the numbers (ATM, with no zoom, they overlap each other a bit. zooming with scroller solves that, but that's just because i've set the tick size to 3600 ... )